# SQL Server Column From Another Table With Static Value In View

Tags: sql-server, database, view

Is there a way to have a column from another table with value which is always the same inside a View> Example:

```
SELECT *, 
   (SELECT value FROM tblStudentPrefixes WHERE PrefixName = 'SeniorPrefix')
   AS StudentPrefix
FROM tblStudents
```

Will the above nested query get executed fro each row? Is there a way to execute it once and use for all rows.

Please note, I'm specifically talking about a View, not a Stored Procedure. I know this can be done in a Stored Procedure.

Comment: if you PrefixName is unique, you could rewrite it as outer join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually depends on your table set up. Unless `prefixName` is constrained to be unique you could come across errors, where the subquery returns more than one row. If it is not constrained to be unique, but happens to be unique for `SeniorPrefix` then your query will be executed 1000 times. To demonstrate I have used the following DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblStudents (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), Filler CHAR(100));
INSERT #tblStudents (Filler)
SELECT TOP 10000 NULL
FROM sys.all_objects a, sys.all_objects b;

CREATE TABLE #tblStudentPrefixes (Value VARCHAR(10), PrefixName VARCHAR(20));
INSERT #tblStudentPrefixes (Value, PrefixName) VALUES ('A Value', 'SeniorPrefix');
```

Running your query gives the following IO output:

> Table '#tblStudentPrefixes'. Scan count 10000, logical reads 10000
>
> Table '#tblStudents'. Scan count 1, logical reads 142

The key being the 1000 logical reads on tblStudentPrefixes. The other problem with it not being constrained to be unique is that if you have duplicates your query will fail with the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

If you can't constrain `PrefixName` to be unique, then you can stop it executing for each row and avoid the errors by using `TOP`:

```
SELECT *, 
   (SELECT TOP 1 value FROM #tblStudentPrefixes WHERE PrefixName = 'SeniorPrefix' ORDER BY Value)
   AS StudentPrefix
FROM #tblStudents
```

The IO now becomes:

> Table '#tblStudentPrefixes'. Scan count 1, logical reads 1
>
> Table '#tblStudents'. Scan count 1, logical reads 142

However, I would still recommend switching to a CROSS JOIN here:

```
SELECT  s.*, p.Value AS StudentPrefix
FROM    #tblStudents AS s
        CROSS JOIN 
        (   SELECT TOP 1 value 
            FROM #tblStudentPrefixes 
            WHERE PrefixName = 'SeniorPrefix'
            ORDER BY Value
        ) AS p;
```

Inspection of the execution plans shows that a sub-select using a table spool which is very unnecessary for a single value:

[image]

So in summary, it depends on your table set up whether it will execute for each row, but regardless you are giving the optimiser a better chance if you switch to a cross join.

---

**EDIT**

In light of the fact that you need to return rows from `tblstudent` when there is no match for `SeniorPrefix` in `tblStudentPrefixes`, and that `PrefixName` is not currenty constrianed to be unique then the best solution is:

```
SELECT *, 
   (SELECT MAX(value) FROM #tblStudentPrefixes WHERE PrefixName = 'SeniorPrefix')
   AS StudentPrefix
FROM #tblStudents;
```

If you do constrain it to be unique, then the following 3 queries produce (essentially) the same plan and the same results, it is simply personal preference:

```
SELECT *, 
   (SELECT value FROM #tblStudentPrefixes WHERE PrefixName = 'SeniorPrefix')
   AS StudentPrefix
FROM #tblStudents;

SELECT  s.*, p.Value AS StudentPrefix
FROM    #tblStudents AS s
        LEFT JOIN #tblStudentPrefixes AS p
            ON p.PrefixName = 'SeniorPrefix';

SELECT  s.*, p.Value AS StudentPrefix
FROM    #tblStudents AS s
        OUTER APPLY 
        (   SELECT Value
            FROM #tblStudentPrefixes 
            WHERE PrefixName = 'SeniorPrefix'
        ) AS p;
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the following which gave me desired results before checking the answers on SO. Do you think this your query will have better performance? `SELECT s.*, p.Value AS StudentPrefix
FROM tblStudents s LEFT JOIN tblStudentPrefixes ON p.PrefixName = 'SeniorPrefix'`

Comment: It depends, but I doubt it. With `LEFT JOIN` if it is constrained to be unique you have the same lazy spool problem described above with the sub-select, and if it is not constrained to be unique you have same problem with a nested loop join and getting 1,000 reads of tblStudentPrefixes.

Comment: I suppose the key question is, will there always be a value for `SeniorPrefix` in tblStudentPrefixes? Do you want to return results if there isn't?

Comment: Yes I'd like to return results if there is no value for `SeniorPrefix`

Comment: And is `PrefixName` constrained to be unique in your table? If not and there is more than one value do you want to return multiple rows?

Comment: I can make it unique and only has to return one value ever for each `PrefixName`.

Comment: @GarethD if the subselect doesn't return any rows. The cross join answer will not return any rows eather, unlike the query in the question would. I believe you should use outer apply instead

Comment: Cheers for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understand your question right, but try this

```
SELECT *  
FROM tblStudents
 Outer Apply 
  (
    SELECT value 
    FROM tblStudentPrefixes 
    WHERE PrefixName = 'SeniorPrefix'
   ) as tble
```

Answer (score 0):

This is OK. Subquery would be executed for every row on every row (which could provide bad performance).
You could try also:

```
SELECT tblStudents.*,StudentPrefix.value 
  FROM tblStudents,
      (SELECT value 
         FROM tblStudentPrefixes 
        WHERE PrefixName = 'SeniorPrefix')StudentPrefix
```